# Using TIFF file in Intersect tool of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, intersect, vectorization

I am attempting to do some geoprocessing with a CSV file and a TIFF file (trying to use the Intersect tool), but am experiencing some trouble with it. I can't seem to be able to input the TIFF file as a layer for the tool.

Do I have to convert the file into another format?

I have never had any formal education in ArcGIS and am teaching myself.

Answer (score 2):

The **Intersect** tool only works with *vector* data.  Tiff files are not vector; they are *raster* data. Accordingly, Arc will not allow you to add rasters to the **Intersect** tool.  You're probably getting a popup error window that says something like "One or more dropped items were invalid and will not be added to the control".

ArcGIS Desktop contains several raster-to-vector conversion tools (their names all seem to start with the phrase "*Raster to ..*".  Try the **Raster to Polygon** tool and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to convert from a raster to a polygon and able to add it to the tool but am now getting an error for the CSV file saying it has no objectID - i am not sure it needs one since it's just coordinates. Any suggestions?